How to compute the derivative of a spline in scipy, including the edges
I'm having trouble with the derivative of spline computed with LSQUnivariateSpine. Specifically that it is generating garbage at the edges.... My example is a bit wierd because I want to specify the knot location rather than letting the algorithm choose (like splrep) but the that should be fine, right?
By eye, I wonder if the derivative might be correct inside knot[1:-1] ? Is there a way of getting a valid derivative across the whole domain?

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import  LSQUnivariateSpline 

# Example noisy data
np.random.seed(42)
NTime = 100
time = np.linspace(0, 1,  NTime)
y_true = np.sin(2 * np.pi * time)
y_noisy = y_true + np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=time.shape)


# Specify the number of knots and their initial locations
n_knots = 10
# Generate n_knots internal knots between the second and second-to-last time points
knots = np.linspace(time[1], time[-2], n_knots)
 
k = 3

# Fit the spline
spline = LSQUnivariateSpline(time, y_noisy, knots, k=3)

# Evaluate the spline and its derivative on a fine mesh
t_fine = np.linspace(time[0], time[-1], 1000)
y_fine = spline(t_fine)
y_fine_derivative = spline.derivative()(t_fine)

# Plot the results
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(time, y_noisy, 'o', label='Noisy Data')
plt.plot(t_fine, y_fine, label='Fitted Spline')
plt.plot(t_fine, y_fine_derivative, label='Derivative')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('LSQUnivariateSpline Fit')
plt.show()


Identical curves generated with tck = splrep(time, y_noisy,t=knots,task=-1); y_fine = splev(t_fine,tck); y_fine_derivative = splev(t_fine, tck, der=1) 

You can use Savitzky–Golay filter implemented as savgol_filter:
from scipy import signal

y_smooth = signal.savgol_filter(y_noisy, 41, 3)
dy_smooth = signal.savgol_filter(y_noisy, 41, 3, deriv=1, delta=np.diff(time)[0])

Then if you need spline object, create it from smoothed data:
n_knots = 10
knots = np.linspace(time[5], time[-6], n_knots)
spline = LSQUnivariateSpline(time, y_smooth, knots, k=3)
y_spline = spline(time)

dspline = spline.derivative(1)
dy_spline = dspline(time)

Graphically:
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
axe.plot(time, y_noisy, linestyle="None", marker='.', label="Data")
axe.plot(time, y_smooth, label="Sav-Gol")
axe.plot(time, dy_smooth, label="Sav-Gol Derivative")
axe.plot(time, y_spline, label="Spline")
axe.plot(time, dy_spline, label="Spline Derivative")
axe.legend()
axe.grid()


Notice your derivative must constrained between [-2 pi, 2 pi] as it is f' = 2 * pi * cos(2 * pi * x)

Yes, that solves the derivative nicely. But I need splines for this particular application to fit into some other part of the workflow.

You can compute your spline and its derivative from the smoothed function, I have updated my answer.

Hm, that is indeed a clever idea. It had not occurred to me to use smoothing filter before attempting to use smoothing splines.

I do note that the computed derivative still has some significant deviation from 2 pi cos(2 pi t) at t=0 and t=1 however.

Will you always smooth a sinus? Because instead of smoothing we can fit wrt a model. But that depends of your requirements.

We have a sensor that does some exotic chemical measurement [I just saw your bio jlandercy, I figure you'd like that!]. It is in a remote location in the dessert and subject to daily temperature variation. We have a sensor measuring temperature, but it is deep inside a metal block. So it measures the "wrong" temperature. The machine learning trick is to take that wrong temperature and back out the actual temp that is corrupting the EPR sensor and thereby temperature correct the sensor. I'm trying to use splines to build the model.

This depends on the choice of knots. For instance:
In [13]: from scipy.interpolate import make_lsq_spline

In [14]: t = np.r_[0, 0, 0,  np.linspace(time[0], time[-1], 10),  1, 1, 1]

In [15]: b = make_lsq_spline(time, y_noisy, t=t)

In [16]: t_fine1 = np.linspace(time[0]-0.1, time[-1]  + .1, 1000)

In [17]: plt.plot(t_fine1, b(t_fine1, nu=1), label='alt knots')

gives you something smooth at 0 and 1 --- whether the result is sensible or not is a separate story. Most likely, it isn't, but it is smooth.
